bulk operation with reformat.sh (bbmap)
I have a folder with paired-end sequencing data in the following format:
Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Bk2-ITS2_S103_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Bk2-ITS2_S103_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Fl1-ITS2_S201_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Fl1-ITS2_S201_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Fl2-ITS2_S202_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Fl2-ITS2_S202_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Mn1-ITS2_S401_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mn1-ITS2_S401_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
Mn2-ITS2_S402_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
Mn2-ITS2_S402_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz

I want to run the following command for the entire folder either using a loop or some wildcard because doing this for each pair of reads is cumbersome and takes a lot time:
reformat.sh in=Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz in2=Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz   out=./reformat/Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz out2=./reformat/Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz mincalledquality=2 maxcalledquality=41 qin=33

So that I achieve the following for all files with modified quality scores and an additional string "reformatted" in name of each file.
Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Bk1-ITS2_S102_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Bk2-ITS2_S103_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Bk2-ITS2_S103_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Fl1-ITS2_S201_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Fl1-ITS2_S201_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Fl2-ITS2_S202_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Fl2-ITS2_S202_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Mn1-ITS2_S401_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Mn1-ITS2_S401_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz`
Mn2-ITS2_S402_L001_R1_001_reformatted.fastq.gz
Mn2-ITS2_S402_L001_R2_001_reformatted.fastq.gz

I can only do it for one pair of reads at a time.
Can someone help me how to achieve this?

What problem are you having? Loop through all the files matching *R1*.fastq.gz, these are the in1 filenames. Replace R1 with R2 to get the in2 filename. Insert _reformatted into the filenames to get the out1 and out2 filenames. Then run reformat.sh with all those arguments.

These are all pretty basic bash operations. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html for how you can do string substitution in shell variables.

It's easy to do with bash.  If you are on Linux there a number of batch rename tools.

since there are 3 additional command line args on the end I'm assuming reformat.sh does more than just rename files ... is this correct?

@markp-fuso, yes, there are other arguments to change the quality score. mincalledquality=2 maxcalledquality=41 qin=33
